# Get data usage for my application in wp

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any method which I can use to see my data usage only for my application in Windows Phone? I used WP 7.1 SDK. I need it to monitoring how much my application using network.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone SDK does not have an API for that.

The only viable way would be to pass all your internet connections through some kind of counter, summing up all the bytes passing through it and saving that. You could also do that for Tile updates, but not for push updates sent to you from the operating system, as you're not the one who makes the call.